# Showing the alert on moving through one page to another by Unsave Change

Tags: c#, asp.net, prompt

Scenario:

I have a CaseEdit.aspx page in which on have 3 buttons:

- AddImage
- FinalPage
- QuestionAns

and one web user controls that CaseContentList.ascx.

In casecontentlist I have datalist in that I am lbtnDisplay.

When we are clicking on caseEdit.aspx btn we are adding the name to the lbtnDisplay (suppose I clicked on btn addimage then addimage will add to dataliast, if btnqusans clicked then qusans will add in that datalist lbtn).

Now, on every btn click I am opening the following web user controls:

- on AddImage click i am opening AddImage.ascx (using tinymce editor)
- on FinalPage click i am opening FinalPage.ascx (using tinymce editor)
- on QuestionAns click i am opening QuestionAns.ascx (using tinymce editor)
- and when i am clicking on datalist link btn (lbtnDisplay) on any item then, PageContent.ascx is opening.

All these things are happening on caseEdit.aspx page.

Requirement:

1. when we are in edit mode of any page and moving to some other page it must show the confirmation alert box.
2. when page content is opened on lbtnDisplay click and then we are going to some other page it should not show the confirmation alert box.

Comment: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function FinalFunction() {
    
          return confirm("Are you sure you have saved your changes?");
    }
        </script> i am using this code

Comment: but by this my 2nd requirement is not getting full fill

Comment: Have a look at onbeforeunload : [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken a hidden field and keeping the value=0, when i am clicking on edit button changing the value to 1 and after that i am comparing the value of text box and hidden filed when user click on some other link its working fine..

```
function ValueChanged() {
     var textvalue;

     textvalue = removeHTMLTags(tinyMCE.get('<%=txbText.ClientID %>').getContent());
     if (textvalue != tinyText) {
         var ssave = window.confirm('Your changes are not saved. Do you want to save your changes before you exit.')
         if (ssave == true) {
             document.getElementById('<%=btnSave.ClientID%>').click();
             return false;
         }
         else
             return true;
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add additional variable that you check before redirecting user to the page:

```
var allowRedirect = false;

function FinalFunction() 
{ 
    if (!allowRedirect)
    {
        return confirm("Are you sure you have saved your changes?"); 
    }
}
```

By default `allowRedirect` s set to false, so all trise to change the page would show confirmation box.

Then, you could set `allowRedirect` to true, when user clicks `lbtnDisplay` button:

```
document.getElementById.onlick = function(){ allowRedirect = true; };
```

Didn't test my code, but it gives you the concept how it could be done.

Comment: No by this it can't solve my issue, because lbtndisplay is in someother control i an just calling that control in my caseedit.aspx page

Comment: this will not work, i am unsave data change alert message box[

Comment: i'm using script but alert is showing on every click wht is need is alert should show when some data gets change on my tinymce is in edit mode.<script type="text/javascript">
var shouldsubmit = false;
var isFiredTwice = false;
window.onbeforeunload = confirmUnloading;
function confirmUnloading() {
if (!shouldsubmit) {
if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") 
{if (!isFiredTwice) {
event.returnValue = "If you have any unsaved data in the current page, it will be lost.";
isFiredTwice = true;
setTimeout("isFiredTwice = false;", 0)}
}else {return "alert msag";}}} </script>